# How to render media compostion to existing file

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to edit a video file with [UWP media composition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-compositions-and-editing#render-the-composition-to-a-video-file) and then save it back to the existing file. However, when I select the same file the rendering doesn't work because the data stream get corrupt.

As a workaround I render the video to a temporary file and move it then to the existing location:

```
// Create temp file
var tempFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
StorageFile tempFile = await tempFolder.CreateFileAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

// Render video to temp file so stream get not corrupted
mediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync(tempFile, MediaTrimmingPreference.Precise);

// If rendering completed move temp file to existing video
await tempFile.MoveAndReplaceAsync(existingFile);
```

My workaround works fine except that the temporary folder is on my local disk and when I edit large video files on my external disk I can run out of storage on my local disk.

Is there another possibility to override an existing file with `RenderToFileAsync()`?

**Update:**

As suggested in the comments I set the file size to zero with the following code but then I get a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
stream.Size = 0;
stream.Dispose();
```

Comment: I would presume RenderToFileAsync doesn't clear the existing contents of the file before writing (either appending to or overwriting data from the start in-place) leading to unexpected behaviour / "corruption" if you then expect it to play as a normal media file, so you'll probably want to open the file and clear it / set the stream size to zero yourself before passing it to RenderToFileAsync.

Comment: Actually I want to read and write to the same file therefore the workaround with the temp file. I need to color correct some underwater videos and after the correction the video should remain in the same file so my video library app doesn't get confused. I hope this makes sense to you... ^^

Comment: Same principle - open the exist file as a stream, set its length / size to zero and close the stream, then pass it to RenderToFileAsync. It's still the same file, you just need to make the file "empty" first because RenderToFileAsync doesn't do it for you.

Comment: I opened the file as a `RandomAccessStream` and set the stream size to zero but then when I try to render the file it throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: @fabwu Any code about how we can reproduce this FileNotFoundException?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Sorry for my late answer but I added some sample code.